# How to do multi threading safely within a list of url to scrape?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, asynchronous, web-scraping

I am scraping multiple url from a list.

It seemed to work, but the outputs are all mixed up and do not correspond to each other.

Here is the code with threading :

```
import requests
import pandas
import json
import concurrent.futures

# our list with multiple profiles
profile=['kaid_329989584305166460858587','kaid_896965538702696832878421','kaid_1016087245179855929335360','kaid_107978685698667673890057','kaid_797178279095652336786972','kaid_1071597544417993409487377','kaid_635504323514339937071278','kaid_415838303653268882671828','kaid_176050803424226087137783']

# two lists of the data that we are going to fill up with each profile
link=[]
projects=[]

############### SCRAPING PART ###############

# my scraping function that we are going to use for each item in profile
def scraper (kaid):
        link.append('https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/{}'.format(kaid))
        data = requests.get('https://www.khanacademy.org/api/internal/user/scratchpads?casing=camel&kaid={}&sort=1&page=0&limit=40000&subject=all&lang=en&_=190425-1456-9243a2c09af3_1556290764747'.format(kaid))
        try:
            data=data.json()
            projects.append(str(len(data['scratchpads'])))
        except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
            projects.append('NA')

# the threading part
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    future_kaid = {executor.submit(scraper, kaid): kaid for kaid in profile}
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_kaid):
        kaid = future_kaid[future]

############### WRITING PART ##############

# Now we write everything into a a dataframe object
d = {'link':link,'projects':projects}
dataframe = pandas.DataFrame(data=d)
print(dataframe)
```

I was expecting this (an output I get without threading):

```
                                                link projects
0  https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/kaid_32998...        0
1  https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/kaid_89696...      219
2  https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/kaid_10160...       22
3  https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/kaid_10797...        0
4  https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/kaid_79717...        0
5  https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/kaid_10715...       12
6  https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/kaid_63550...      365
7  https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/kaid_41583...       NA
8  https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/kaid_17605...        2
```

But instead, I get this:

```
                                                link projects
0  https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/kaid_32998...        0
1  https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/kaid_89696...        0
2  https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/kaid_10160...        0
3  https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/kaid_10797...       22
4  https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/kaid_79717...       NA
5  https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/kaid_10715...       12
6  https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/kaid_63550...        2
7  https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/kaid_41583...      219
8  https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/kaid_17605...      365
```

It looks the same, but actually we can see that our `link` does not correspond correctly to our `projects`. It is mixed up.

My code without threading is the same except for the `SCRAPING PART`

```
# first part of the scraping
for kaid in profile:
    link.append('https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/{}'.format(kaid))

# second part of the scraping
for kaid in profile:
    data = requests.get('https://www.khanacademy.org/api/internal/user/scratchpads?casing=camel&kaid={}&sort=1&page=0&limit=40000&subject=all&lang=en&_=190425-1456-9243a2c09af3_1556290764747'.format(kaid))
    try:
        data=data.json()
        projects.append(str(len(data['scratchpads'])))
    except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
        projects.append('NA')
```

What is wrong with my threading code? Why it is getting all mixed up?

Comment: Your links arent being correctly associated with the number of projects, I'd assume that this is because you aren't assigning them together within the Thread, hence timings would mess it up if one thread completes before the other

Comment: In the scraper function, I'd assign the links and projects to the dictionary together in one go instead of them separately as they could be entered at different times, with threading that becomes messy

Comment: @Max Yes indeed. Thus, which line is not correct? How do I assign them together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this? Instead of appending to links and then appending to projects after some time consuming code execution, append them sequentially, should fix the problem. But I'm thinking of a better method atm...

```
d = {'link' : [], 'projects' : []}

############### SCRAPING PART ###############

# my scraping function that we are going to use for each item in profile
def scraper (kaid):
        link = 'https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/{}'.format(kaid)
        data = requests.get('https://www.khanacademy.org/api/internal/user/scratchpads?casing=camel&kaid={}&sort=1&page=0&limit=40000&subject=all&lang=en&_=190425-1456-9243a2c09af3_1556290764747'.format(kaid))
        try:
            data=data.json()
            projects = str(len(data['scratchpads']))
        except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
            projects ='NA'
        d['link'].append(link)
        d['projects'].append(projects)
```

***Different solution (ish, not really)***

Or better yet, return both link and projects at the end of the thread execution and then add them then... (This im not sure if it will work)

```
def scraper (kaid):
        link = 'https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/{}'.format(kaid)
        data = requests.get('https://www.khanacademy.org/api/internal/user/scratchpads?casing=camel&kaid={}&sort=1&page=0&limit=40000&subject=all&lang=en&_=190425-1456-9243a2c09af3_1556290764747'.format(kaid))
        try:
            data=data.json()
            projects = str(len(data['scratchpads']))
        except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
            projects = 'NA'
        return link, projects

# the threading part
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    future_kaid = {executor.submit(scraper, kaid): kaid for kaid in profile}
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_kaid):
        kaid = future_kaid[future]
        data = future.result()
        link.append(data[0])
        projects.append(data[1])
```

I'd say the second one is the better solution as this waits for all the threads to be executed before processing all the data into the DataFrame. With the first one there is still the possibility that misalignment in timings can occur (however these are incredibly slim as we are talking mere ticks of difference in clocks speeds of gigahertz, but just to eliminate that chance completely, the second option is better).

Comment: The second solution is working fine. The first solution I get an empty dataframe (but maybe I wrote this wrong, did you change the way it is writing into dataframe too? What about the lists `link` and `project`, did you deleted them?).

Comment: Yes exactly that. Instead of first writing to a list and then putting the list in the dictionary, I created the dictionarys with the keys and the lists predefined and just added to them.

Comment: I get the logic, but the first proposition is still not working. It's like `d['links'].append(link)` and `d['projects'].append(projects)` are not adding anything to our dictionary `d`. When I `print(d)` after the threading is done, I get `{'link': [], 'projects': []}`. Any idea why?

Comment: @RobZ have you removed the line `# Now we write everything into a a dataframe object
d = {'link':link,'projects':projects}`?

As that would overwrite `d`

Comment: yes I did, I only have `dataframe = pandas.DataFrame(data=d)
print(dataframe)`. :/

Comment: Okay, give me a sec

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192690/discussion-between-max-and-robz).

Comment: Found my error! Inside the function, I wrote `d['links'].append(link)` instead of `d['link'].append(link)`

Comment: Did that fix it all?

Comment: Yes! Thank you Max